# Validating presence of at least one field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been stuck on this for some time and can't figure out how to validate at least one field for `superpower`. In other words, if at least one field is filled, the other fields can be left blank. I did use `reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}` for `superpowers`, but doing so will allow the form to be submitted when all the three superpower fields are left blank, and that's not what I want.

[Here is a screenshot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c35YA.png)

superpower.rb

```
class Superpower < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :superhero
    
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

superhero.rb

```
class Superhero < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :superhero_teams
    has_many :teams, through: :superhero_teams
    has_many :superpowers

    validates_presence_of :name 
    validates_uniqueness_of :name 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :superpowers, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}

end
```

Comment: try: `proc { |attributes| attributes.all?(&:blank?) }`

Comment: @Emu I tried that, but it didn't work. I left all the `superpower` fields blank, and it submitted the form without running the validation.

Comment: Did you declared the strong_parameters? In your console, did you checked if you send any value in one of the `superpower` field is it passing via POST/PATCH call?

Comment: Yes, here is my params from `superhero` controller:     'params.require(:superhero).permit(:name, :user_id, team_ids:[], teams_attributes: [:name], superpowers_attributes: [:name])`

Comment: and yes, the values do pass when I checked it in `pry`

Comment: You're confusing some very different things. The `reject_if:` option just lets you reject a set of nested attributes if it doesn't match the criteria. It does not in any way restrict if the parent item can be created or not. Thats what validations do. If you want to prevent form submssions from happening at all you need to use client side validations. ActiveModel::Validations will prevent the record from being created on the server side **after** the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

As a convenience you can instead pass the symbol `:all_blank` which will create a proc that will reject records where all the attributes are blank excluding any value for `_destroy`:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :superpowers, reject_if: :all_blank`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a new validation

```
  validates_presence_of :superpowers
```

So, you will reject the superpower if the name is blank, and this new validation will ensure at least one superpower has the name.